# Airflow task is failing with ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, ansible, airflow, airflow-scheduler

This task uses an ansible-playbook to submit a spark job, the spark job is getting completed but the Airflow task is failing with

> ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state.

This is how my YAML looks like:

```
# test.yml
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: user
  tasks:
    - name: change the working directory to /home/  and  runs command.
      shell: "/path_to_spark_submit/spark-submit --master yarn-client <spark-submit>"
      args:
        chdir: /path_to_spark_submit/
      ignore_errors: True
      register: command_result
    - name: change the working directory to /home/  and  runs command.
      shell: <some_command>     
      args:
        chdir: /tmp
      ignore_errors: True
      when: command_result.rc != 0

    - fail:
         msg: extract was failed
      when: command_result.rc != 0
```

I tried removing the register variable, in case of both success/failure of the job, the task is going to the next task without any issue.
One more thing, I am getting a huge log from the cluster, how can I limit these logs?
What can be the possible cause of this error?

Comment: do you know which "worker" is dead ? is it the spark worker ? or  airflow ?

Comment: Spark is running properly, it is airflows'

Comment: have you tried any simpler airflow task ? is it working ?

Comment: @Steven yes it is working fine.

Comment: then, check the ressources allocated to your airflow worker. Maybe spark requires too much memory and it kills your worker.

Comment: @Steven My airflow and spark run on separate clusters. Can spark kill my airflow worker? Can you suggest any other alternative? so that it works.

Comment: They may run on a different cluster but where is the spark driver ? if the driver is your aiflow machine, then it need ressources